# Replacing strings in its entirity

Tags: python, string

I want to replace words if it matches with a string entirely in Python.

Suppose,

```
 st = 'Length Le'.
```

I want to replace all words 'le' with <=

Result has to be

```
'Length <='
```

I tried this with replace() and re.sub() but it gives me

```
'<=ngth <='
```

Is there any inbuilt function for this operation?

Comment: `replace` just works fine for me.

Comment: How can you specify the `le` you're interested in? whitespace around it? word boundaries? Regex might be the best option

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://sscce.org or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i edited it. le has to be Le

Comment: were you using `le` or `Le`?

Comment: @Padraic I was using Le.

Comment: @Padraic Yes there is a space

Comment: I was going to suggest what Basic has, re is probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
import re
s = "Length Le"
re.sub(r'\bLe\b', '<=', s)
```

It will match the regular expression `\bLe\b` and replace all matches with `<=`. The expression means `"Le" where it's not surrounded by alphanumeric characters`. In effect, where `Le` is surrounded by whitespace or punctuation.

The Python documentation on [Regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is worth a read, specifically look at `\b` which matches a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know that `le` will be a word of its own, you can replace it when it has spaces before and after.  The caveat is you will have to change your string from `'Length le'` to `'Length le '`.

```
>>> s1 = 'Length le '
>>> s2 = 'length le '
>>> s3 = ' le length'
>>> s1.replace(' le ', '<= ')
'Length <='
>>> s2.replace(' le ', '<= ')
'length <='
>>> s3.replace(' le ', '<= ')
'<= length'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression `\b` to match a **word boundary** - such a zero-width string that on one side has non-word character, and on the other side has a word-character.

Optionally also use `re.I` for ignore case, and `re.U` for Unicode string match if you have non-Ascii words, and you are using Python 2...

Thus we get a regex `\ble\b` which stands for *a word boundary, followed by `l`, `e`, and a word boundary*. With `re.I` the case is ignored so `l` will also match `L` and `e` will also match `E`.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Length Le le ale"
>>> re.sub(r'\ble\b', '<=', string, flags=re.I|re.U)
'Length <= <= ale'
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice it!

```
st = 'Length Le'
if st.endswith(' Le'):
    st = st[0:len(st)-3] + " <="
print st
Length <=
```

Takes the variable st, checks to see if it ends with " Le", if true, using string slicing the ending " Le" is removed and the " <=" is then added. This is considering your input for var st will always be static in form and adhere to a certain format.